# Calling a function in Solidity

Tags: javascript, solidity

I am calling the following function:

```
test: function()
    {
        alert("test1");

        let meta
        LoyaltyCard.deployed().then(function (instance) {
            meta = instance
            alert("test");
        }).catch(function (e) {
            alert(e);
        })

        //})
    }
```

and when calling it as follows:

```
<button type="button" onclick="App.test()">TEST</button>
```

Unfortunately when calling this part:

```
}).catch(function (e) {
                alert(e);
```

I get the following:

> Error: LoyaltyCard has not been deployed to detected network
>   (network/artifact mismatch)

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use await and async while interacting with the web3 library. Below is a sample i used to get the instance of the deployed contract using angular 6.

```
  async getInstance() {
       await this.web3Service.artifactsToContract(artifacts)
       .then((uLoanAbstraction) => {
        this.LoanAbstraction = uLoanAbstraction;
       });

       this.deployedLoans = await this.uLoanAbstraction.deployed();
       // Later in the app i use this.deployedLoans to interact with the smart contract
 }
```